# Avoid side effect of workbooks.open a .csv file

Tags: excel, vba, csv

i'm using vba to open an .csv file

```
Sub open_csv_file()        
    Workbooks.Open("c:\test.csv")
    ActiveWorkbook.Close    
End Sub
```

It works, but with a side effect: when the csv file is opened, the original .xlsm file start to recalculate.

Is there a way to avoid the side effect?

ps. I've already set Excel calculation as Manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to avoid the calculation is to open the file with another instance of Excel:

```
Dim app As Excel.Application
Dim csv As Workbook

Set app = New Excel.Application
app.Visible = True

Set csv = app.Workbooks.Open("c:\test.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

The only workaround that seems to be working is to set Worksheet.EnableCalculation to False for each worksheet.

Try this

```
Sub open_csv_file()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.EnableCalculation = False
    Next ws
    Workbooks.Open ("c:\users\test\desktop\test.csv")
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: yes it works. however, why have to set each worksheet enablecalculation false? as i've already set excel so. mysterious excel...

Comment: It seems it a known issue and it has something to do with the volatile behaviour of excel.

Answer (score 1):

The calling .xlsm file recalculates when opening a .csv file, but not when opening a .xls file. Renaming the .csv file to .xls before opening will prevent recalculation and still open the file as normal.

```
Sub open_csv_file()
    Name "c:\test.csv" As "c:\test.xls"
    Workbooks.Open "c:\test.xls", Format:=2
End Sub
```

Some error handling should be added to handle the situation where the new filename already exists.

Comment: it's not perfect -- the file is opened, without triggering recalculation, but all rows are having only 1 column, comma no longer works as delimiters...

Comment: As it was, my solution worked for tab delimited files only (which is what I usually see saved as .csv files). I've updated my solution to work with true comma separate value files. The "Format:=2" says to use commas as delimiters when opening.